# Detecting temporal types in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there some way, within a cypher query, to have a `WHERE` clause select only records where a given property is a temporal type?

Answer (score 0):

The [apoc.meta.type](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_meta_graph) function can be used. For example:

```
MATCH (f:Foo)
WHERE apoc.meta.type(f.bar) IN ['LocalTime', 'OffsetTime', 'ZonedDateTime', 'LocalDateTime']
RETURN f;
```